# Excel VBA InternetExplorer.document - Automation/unspecified error

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am new to the wonderful world of excel VBA. I am trying to scrape some data from our company page. As you can see in the picture I get the Automation/unspecified error. Any ideas? It does not matter which page I open, once I start to use the document it leads to errors.

```
Sub PMM()
    
    'declaration
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim ht As HTMLDocument
    Dim UserName As String, Password As String, LoginData As Worksheet
    Set LoginData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    UserName = LoginData.Cells(1, "B").Value
    Password = LoginData.Cells(2, "B").Value
    
    'Inicialization
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.navigate ("http://czpskmii0021.ls.ege.ds:50000/XMII/CM/SC_MAINTENANCE/Report/WorkOrderList.irpt")
    document = ie.document.getElementById("logonuidfield")
    'Set ht = ie.document
    'ht.getElementById ("logonuidfield")


End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by changing the Internet options -> Security -> Enable Protected Mode

[Protected mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYudm.png)